# Multiple onload events with javascript Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to chain multiple promises into `Promise.all([...])` and activate each Promise in `onload` callback. My code:

```js
var styleSheetPromises = []

// styles version
for (var link of iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll("link[rel=stylesheet]")) {

    //var linkPromise = new Promise((resolve) => resolve()) 
    var linkPromise = () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve())

    styleSheetPromises.push(linkPromise)

    link.onload = function () {
        console.log('stylesheet loaded')

        //linkPromise()
    }

    link.href = link.href.replace(/\?.*|$/, "?v=4")
}

Promise.all(styleSheetPromises).then((values) => {
    console.log('All stylesheets are loaded')
});
```

The above code is appending the version of stylesheets in an iframe and determining when all stylesheets are loaded in `Promise.all`.

The issue in my code is that `Promise.all` is activating without calling  `linkPromise()` in the onload event callback. will log "All stylesheets are loaded" before "stylesheet loaded".

How can I properly chain the Promises and activate them in an `onload` event and use `Promise.all` callback to determine when all promises are resolved?

Comment: Why would `Promise.all` call anything? It expects an array of promises. Not an array of functions that return promises.

Comment: ahhh i missed that @VLAZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll("link[rel=stylesheet]")).forEach(link=> {
    // change to arrow function to fix closure scoping issues

    link.href = link.href.replace(/\?.*|$/, "?v=4");
    styleSheetPromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        // Only resolve the promise when the stylesheet is loaded
        link.addEventListener('load', resolve)
    }));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative method which does not need an event listener:

```
for (var link of iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll("link[rel=stylesheet]")) {
    styleSheetPromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        link.onload = function () {
            console.log('stylesheet loaded')
            resolve()
        }
    }))
    link.href = link.href.replace(/\?.*|$/, "?v=4")
}

Promise.all(styleSheetPromises).then((values) => {
    console.log('All stylesheets are loaded')
});
```

Comment: I like this response but you should also handle `link.onerror` otherwise if a css link fails Promise.all(...) will never be fulfilled.