# Inject external and inline <script> tags and then run them

Tags: javascript, dom, async-await, promise

QUESTION:
I have an array of scripts referencing libraries hosted on a CDN i.e. `<script src="https://link.to.script.js">` and an array of scripts with inline JS i.e. `<script>alert('inline code!')</script>`. How can I write code to await loading ALL of the external scripts and THEN execute the inline scripts.

BACKGROUND:
I would like to append an HTML element to my document. This HTML element may have 0 to many javascript tags inside of it as `<script>` tags. Some of these tags contain inline javascript while others reference external third party libraries hosted on CDN.

For example something like...

```
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>The below script imports Splide</p>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/js/splide.min.js">
  <div class="splide">
    <!-- ... more html that splide expects -->
  </div>
  <script>
    alert('Here is some inline code')
    let splide = new Splid('.splide')
    // more JS to customize splide
  </script>
</div>
```

Normally, I would just put the `<script>` tags right before the `</body>` tag or in the `<head>` section with defer attribute but in this case I don't have control over where the inner `<script>` tags get loaded

I did some searching already and have been able to get something working with the below code:

```
document.querySelector('[wb-data="preview-wrapper"]')?.append(elToAdd)
    const scriptTags = elToAdd.querySelectorAll('script')
    console.log(scriptTags)
    let scriptsExternal: Array<HTMLScriptElement> = [];
    let scriptsInline: Array<HTMLScriptElement> = [];
    scriptTags.forEach(async (scriptTag) => {
      if (scriptTag.src !== "") {
        scriptsExternal.push(scriptTag)
      } else {
        scriptsInline.push(scriptTag);
      }
    })
    console.log({ scriptsExternal })
    console.log({ scriptsInline })
    scriptsExternal.forEach((scriptExt) => {
      (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.onload = function () {
          // remote script has loaded
          console.log('remote script has loaded')
          scriptsInline.forEach((scriptIn) => {
            eval(scriptIn.innerHTML)
          })
        };
        js.src = scriptExt.src;
        fjs.parentNode?.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'gallery'));
    })
```

However, I suspect it will have problems if I am loading multiple scripts with src attribute as I call eval() within .onload for each.

Thank you!

Comment: If you can't control the inline scripts, I'm afraid there's nothing you can do.

Comment: If I can control the inline scripts then what would you recommend?

Comment: I would get rid of the inline scripts, and loaded all scripts from files, tags set with `defer`.

Comment: Thanks. Wondering if there's not a way to use Promise.all and link the external scripts onload function to a Promise resolver. Looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016273/multiple-onload-events-with-javascript-promise

Comment: It's possible, but the inline scripts are parsed in-place, I'm not sure whether the scripts are run before the promises are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working but I'm going to keep testing it:

```
document.querySelector('[wb-data="preview-wrapper"]')?.append(elToAdd)
    const scriptTags = elToAdd.querySelectorAll('script')
    scriptTags.forEach((scriptTag) => {
      if (scriptTag.src !== "") {
        scriptsExternal.push(scriptTag)
      } else {
        scriptsInline.push(scriptTag);
      }
    })
    // console.log({ scriptsExternal })
    // console.log({ scriptsInline })
    const externalScriptsPromises: Promise<any>[] = [];

    (scriptsExternal.forEach((scriptExt, index) => {
      externalScriptsPromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        (function (d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.onload = resolve;
          js.async = true;
          js.src = scriptExt.src;
          fjs.parentNode?.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'wb'));
      }))
    }))

    Promise.all(externalScriptsPromises).then((values) => {
      // console.log('all external scripts loaded, ', values)
      scriptsInline.forEach(scriptInline => {
        // execute inline scripts
        eval(scriptInline.innerHTML)
      })
    })
```